# CodeIgniter datalist foreach option not selected in edit

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, datalist

In my `CodeIgniter v3` project `datalist` option not selected in edit page.

**My code:**

```
<input class="form-control list" list="processListOptions" name="processPlaningTextList[<?= $i?>][processId]" id="processId[<?= $i?>]" placeholder="This is a search placeholder" value="" required>
<datalist id="processListOptions">
   <option value=""></option>
   <?php foreach($processLists as $process){ ?>
   <option data-value="<?=$process['processId']?>" <?= $processData['processId'] == $process['processId'] ? 'selected' : ''?> ><?=$process['processName']?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</datalist>
<input type="hidden" name="processPlaningList[<?= $i?>][processId]" id="processId[<?= $i?>]-hidden">
```

**datalist:**

[image]

**not selected datalist:**

[image]

Check the above image `process name` is not selected.

I tried to add `value` in `<input>`, but value comes under `foreach`. So am not able to add value in `<input>`.